# How to get the recent message from Gmail Webhooks?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail Webhooks to be notified about changes in my inbox.

When I receive a new message I also receive a webhook with a cursor to fetch **subsequent** messages from that time.

However, I'm interested also in this particular message which triggered the webhook.

Is there any way to fetch this initial (the first one) message?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Users.history: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) which lists the history of all the changes to the given mailbox in chronological order (increasing `historyId`). Acceptable history types are:

- "labelAdded"
- "labelRemoved"
- "messageAdded"
- "messageDeleted"

Please note, you need to specify `startHistoryId` which can be obtained from the `historyId` of received notifications in updates that matches your `watch`.

See [receiving notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#receiving_notifications) for more information.

Comment: The problem with it is that the `historyId` gives me the **history**, not the message I want to see.